# No se actualiza mi Javascript cuando hago cambios utilizando MAMP

Tags: javascript, localhost

lo que ocurre es que estoy modificando un archivo javascript, cuando hago los cambios no los detecta en mi localhost.

Estoy usando MAMP para esto, pero cuando voy a la pagina y le doy inspeccionar para ver los archivos resulta que no se aplicaron los cambios, pero si modifico el html, los cambios si se ven reflejados cuando actualizo la pagina. Si entro directamente a mi html (el que tengo en mi pc) tambien carga mi Javascript con todos mis cambios, únicamente es con el localhost.  Lo raro es que ayer todo me funcionaba sin problemas, pero hoy no.

Mi cambio fue el siguiente

```
function registerUser() {
var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.then(function(){
    authEmail();
})}
```

y ahora es:

```
function registerUser() {
var email = document.getElementById('emailRegister').value;
var password = document.getElementById('passwordRegister').value;
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.then(function(){
    authEmail();
})}
```

Lo que modifique es el id en el html, por lo que aquí también debo cambiarlo, aun así no lo hace, en localhost me carga la primera, sin los cambios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto se debe a que los navegadores almacenan en caché los archivos, bien sea imágenes, css, js, pdf, entre otros... para no tener que descargarlos constantemente cuando se visite el mismo sitio.

Para forzar al navegador a descargar de nuevo los archivos de un sitio debes pulsar:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>

En algunos navegadores el comando es:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

En google chrome si tienes abiertas las herramientas de desarrollador (<kbd>F12</kbd>) te permite al pulsar con el botón derecho del mouse sobre el ícono de recarga de la página indicar si quieres forzar la carga de los archivos o eliminar toda la caché del sitio y volver a recargarlo.

Por todo ésto sucede que cuando tenemos problemas con algún sitio lo primero que nos piden si hablamos con el soporte del mismo es eliminar la caché y los cookies ya que a veces las páginas nos funcionan debido a que tenemos versiones viejas de los .js en nuestra caché.

De nuevo és un comportamiento de los navegadores, por lo cual debes tenerlo en cuenta, también se puede desactivar la caché del navegador pero eso hará que siempre se carguen las págnas completas por lo que puede llegar a ser lento si tiene muchos elementos, además de que si tienes un plan por consumo de mb ésto hará que gastes más por ejemplo.

Comment: En herramientas de desarrollador, para que la recarga actualice la cache, en el tab de Network hay un checkbox "Disable cache" que debe estar tildado.

Answer (score 2):

Este problema se puede abrir en dos escenarios:

1) Cuando desarrollas:

Aplican las técnicas de @zerocool.

2) Cuando tenes la versión final y lo pones productivo, lo mismo le pasa a los usuarios del sitio, pero por obvias razones no podes resetearles a ellos la caché.

Una técnica común para este caso es agregarle a la url del javascript una versión como query parameter.

Ejemplo:

Si la url es `https://www.example.com/js/mi-archivo-javascript.js`, le agregas `?v=10.2.34`, quedando `https://www.example.com/js/mi-archivo-javascript.js?v=10.2.34`.

La version en sí puede ser cualquiera, el tema es ir cambiándola cada vez que haces una actualización.
Al hacer esto el navegador, al encontrar una nueva versión, pedirá nuevamente el archivo, y actualiza la caché. (Esto se conoce como 'cache busting', es la técnica que utiliza wordpress por ejemplo).